# Adding days, hours, and minutes to a timestamp - PHP

Tags: php

I am having difficulty adding days, hours, and minutes through `strtotime()`.

Code:

```
$uncleanTotal = strtotime($created_time);
$uncleanTotal = strtotime("+".$timeForUnclean[0] . " days ". $timeForUnclean[1] ." hours ". $timeForUnclean[2] ." minutes");
```

To be more exact I am trying to get a time from before and add days, hours, and minutes to see if that time it creates is greater than the current time (now) or lesser than.  I am than using an `if` statement to check this.

Code:

```
if($cautionTotal <= $now)
{
    echo "working caution";
    return "yellow";

}
else if( $uncleanTotal <= $now)
{
    echo  "working unclean";
    return "red";
}
else if($cautionTotal > $now && $uncleanTotal > $now)
{
    echo  "working clean";
    return "green";
}
```

Suggestions? Thoughts?

Comment: to which date you try to add hours and minutes? that seems to be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the source date in the statement where you're doing the addition:

Try:

```
$uncleanTotal = strtotime($created_time . "+".$timeForUnclean[0] . " days ". $timeForUnclean[1] ." hours ". $timeForUnclean[2] ." minutes");
```

Alternatively you can pass `strtotime($created_time)` as the second parameter to `strtotime` to get the same result as above:

```
$uncleanTotal = strtotime("+".$timeForUnclean[0] . " days ". $timeForUnclean[1] ." hours ". $timeForUnclean[2] ." minutes", strtotime($created_time));
```

Comment: Thank you!  I actually did this: `$uncleanTotal += strtotime("+".$timeForUnclean[0] . " days ". $timeForUnclean[1] ." hours ". $timeForUnclean[2] ." minutes",$created_time);` - Is this okay?

Comment: @DavidBiga, the second parameter has to be timestamp.  Please see: [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)

Comment: I am using it and it works perfectly, the created time itself is in the format of `2014-02-01 17:45:57`.

Comment: @DavidBiga, I've never used a date directly as you've shown, I guess because PHP manual specifically says `int` and `timestamp`.  Thank you for pointing this out, will definitely try.